# Playing sounds for blips on a Radar

Tags: python, audio, pygame, playback

I have a circular radar. The "arm" of the radar revolves at a constant speed. I need the blips on the radar to play a sound whenever they're passed.

How do I go about solving this problem so that every revolution I'm guaranteed a hit?

(Using pygame)

I've tried using an if statement to catch whether or not the (x, y) coordinates of the "arm" and the blips are equivalent. However I don't get consistent success. I've also tried taking slope measurements and cosine measurements and checking if they're equivalent between the arm and the blips; I don't get consistent success in realtime and when there is a hit there are usually two played at the positions where the cos is the same on the circle. Because the arm is accurate to many more decimal places than the positions of the blips it's difficult it seems for me to get a good catch with the if statement. I'm not sure how else to go about this. Any ideas would be appreciated!

[image: janky radar]

Code snippet:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math

SIZE = 800, 800

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
done = False
bpm = 180 # based on a metronome to easily modulate speed
bbpm = 4
spm = bbpm*60/bpm
turnsPerMs = 1/(1000*spm) 
startTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
color = Color("red")
CENTER = (400,400)
RADIUS = 200
lineLen = 100
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 200)
BACKGROUND = (218, 226, 235)


pygame.init()

class Blip:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mouse = (0, 0)
        self.vector = (self.mouse[0] - CENTER[0], self.mouse[1] - CENTER[1])
        self.distance = math.sqrt(self.vector[0] ** 2 + self.vector[1] ** 2)
        self.scalar = RADIUS / self.distance
        self.lineend = (int(round(CENTER[0] + self.vector[0] * self.scalar)), int(round(CENTER[1] + self.vector[1] * self.scalar)))
        self.radius = 20
        self.position = (self.lineend[0] - self.radius, self.lineend[0] + self.radius, self.lineend[1] - self.radius,
                        self.lineend[1] + self.radius)
        self.o = 255
        self.s = 200
        self.t = 150

"""def load_sound(self, filename):
        print(filename)
        self.sound = pygame.mixer.music.load(filename)"""

   def play_sound(self):
        print("Blip!")

   def draw_blip(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (100, 150, 200), self.lineend, self.radius)

class TickArm:
    def __init__(self):
    self.timeDelta = 0
    self.revDelta = 0
    self.deltaRadian = 0
    self.x = SIZE[0]/2
    self.y = SIZE[1]/2

    def draw_tickarm(self):
        self.timeDelta = pygame.time.get_ticks() - startTime
        self.revDelta = self.timeDelta*turnsPerMs;
        self.deltaRadian = self.revDelta*2*math.pi;
        self.x = CENTER[0] + math.cos(self.deltaRadian) * RADIUS
        self.y = CENTER[1] + math.sin(self.deltaRadian) * RADIUS

        # then render the line ->(x,y)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color, CENTER, (self.x,self.y), 1)

tickarm = TickArm()
blip = Blip()

while not done:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT or (e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE):
            done = True
            break

    screen.fill((BACKGROUND))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, CENTER, RADIUS, 2)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, CENTER, RADIUS-25, 2)
    blip.draw_blip()
    tickarm.draw_tickarm()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: It's hard to give an answer without knowing how the arm is implemented. However, I believe it should be work to divide your radar into sections or reasonable size, and then check in which section the x, y position of the arm is located. If the section contains a dot then play the sound. So instead of checking whether the dot and the arm position is equal (which won't work because I presume they are in floats) you check whether their position are near within a margin.

Comment: Thank you! I just took a good long walk and had a similar idea. I can make a bounding box for each of the dots and if the arm is within the bounding box I can make the blip play a sound. It might work! I'm just thinking that since the arm moves so fast it might be difficult to transition from box to box. If it doesn't work I'll definitely go for a 'nearest neighbor' approach like you say and see how that works. I'll also post the code for the arm/dots so one can have a better idea of the implementation.

Comment: It'd make more sense to calculate the *angle* of each blip (using `math.atan2` with its X/Y coordinates) and play the sound in whichever frame the arm's angle will "cross" that of the blip.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment. Sorry!
But you can try this:

```
screen.get_at(x,y)
```

How to go:
store the centers of all blips in a tuple center_lists

```
for i in center_lists:
    if screen.get_at(i) == green:
        #play the sound
```

what you do is check the color of centers of all blips on each frame. If they are green you can play sound. You can even go further to create another tuple having different sounds for different type of blips and use the iterator count i to play the respective one.